# org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory not found within HttpClientBuilder.build()

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

When I call this code:

```
HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create(); 
LaxRedirectStrategy laxStrategy = new LaxRedirectStrategy();
clientBuilder = clientBuilder.setRedirectStrategy(laxStrategy);

httpClient = clientBuilder.build();   // FAILS HERE
```

I get java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Looks like it can't find the class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory, however that class is found in a jar on my classpath.  How can I find the culprit?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 2):

you have a different version of Apache Commons HTTP Client on your classpath. you can try below version with jdk 8.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dependency issue to me. May be the Class you are looking for is present in two different jars on your CP.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen while initializing SSLConnectionSocketFactory field:

```java
public static final X509HostnameVerifier ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
    = AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
```

In my case the org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier class did not have the INSTANCE field because it was shaded (patched) from tika-app.

Check in which dependency (jar) you have this class and how does it look like. If possible try to exclude the containing dependency or ugprade it to a version which has correct AllowAllHostnameVerifier.